# PhpStorm index.css file doesn't work, even the content of index.css is empty , the page are same as before?

Tags: php, css, phpstorm

index.php

[image: picture one]

[image]

In chrome: 
[image]

And even I deleted the `index.css`,the web page is same.

What's going on here?

[image]

Do you need any other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to restart phpStorm, if it doesnt help try `<link href=./css/index.css rel="stylesheet">` Also clear cash from browser and reload the page.